# understanding syslog logs format

Tags: linux, syslog

Im geting syslogs from multiple servers, and Im having trouble to understand some syslog logs, here is one example

```
<189>12593340: 16596512: Jul  6 20:31:09: %PARSER-5-CFGLOG_LOGGEDCMD: User:someuser  logged command:no 1480
```

the first number inside <> is the priority, but the two numbers after that: "12593340" and "16596512" I dont know what their are.

Does anyone knows what are those numbers?
how many formats the syslog logs has?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specified in the Syslog RFC:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.2.1

Some years ago I wrote a Shell script to calculate the numbers:

https://gist.github.com/ceving/b32d4986f43d66f252ef